# add files to List(String) in certain order

Tags: vb.net

I added a list of files in a directory to List(Of String)(). I need help in putting these files in a certain order. For example if I have files 1, 2, 3,4 in the list, how can I put the files in let say 4,2,1,3 order?

```
 Dim aryFi As FileInfo() = di.GetFiles("*.pdf")
 Dim fi As FileInfo

 Dim fileInput As New List(Of String)()

 For Each fi In aryFi
     fileInput.Add(fi.Name)
 Next
```

Comment: And how is this certain order defined?

Comment: By file name. Each file name starts with an identifier like "Po-xyz.pdf", "Invoice-yyx.pdf", "Sup-wrt.pdf", etc... So I would like the files in the following order Sup-wrt.pdf, Invoice-yyx.pdf and Po-xyz.pdf.

Comment: The easiest way is probably to sort the files into different lists for each `Po`, `Sup`, and `Invoice`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim fileInput As New List(Of String)

For Each fi as FileInfo in di.GetFiles("Sup-wrt.pdf")
    fileInput.Add(fi.Name)
Next
For Each fi as FileInfo in di.GetFiles("Invoice-*.pdf")
    fileInput.Add(fi.Name)
Next
For Each fi as FileInfo in di.GetFiles("Po-*.pdf")
    fileInput.Add(fi.Name)
Next
```

Comment: Thank you. One question, how can I GetFiles to lowercase?

Comment: Do you mean you want all the strings in the list to be lowercase? If so, use `fileInput.Add(fi.Name.ToLower)`.